# Where can i find project management system data?

Tags: data-request, database

I am searching for datasets related to project management system.Project planing details such as project name,milestones,tasks and time.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get the dataset related to projects, milestones, tasks!!

You can search for Kaggle for the required dataset.

- Link: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets

Following other dataset resources might be useful too.

- https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html
- http://www.rdatamining.com/resources/data
- https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html
- https://www.springboard.com/blog/free-public-data-sets-data-science-project/
- https://dreamtolearn.com/ryan/1001_datasets
- https://blog.bigml.com/2013/02/28/data-data-data-thousands-of-public-data-sources/
- https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/11/25-websites-to-find-datasets-for-data-science-projects/
- http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awm/15781/project/data.html
- https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/all/
- http://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup
- https://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/index.html
- http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dme/html/datasets0405.html
- http://bigdata-madesimple.com/70-websites-to-get-large-data-repositories-for-free/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/

Comment: Thanks for your time. But it seems impossible to find this kind of data!

Comment: @jessjess Yeah. I don't think project management/planning details will be available in the market. But maybe you can try generating synthetic data for your requirement.